# Yii query incorrect function used with model retrieval

Tags: mysql, database, yii, orm, models

I am trying to amend an existing function - I just want to pass the retreive all the rows then count how many rows the query has returned

This is what I have so far.. can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

I get a Property "AccountMenu.user" is not defined error?

```
        return OrganisationNews::model()->findByCriteria('
                (organisation_id=:org_id OR organisation_id=0) AND
                (site_id=:site_id OR site_id IS NULL OR site_id=:empty) AND
                (year_id=:year_id OR year_id=0) AND
                (form_name=:form_name OR form_name IS NULL OR form_name=:empty) AND
                (postcode_area=:postcode_area OR postcode_area IS NULL) AND
                active=1'.(($showRead)?'':' AND t.news_id NOT IN (SELECT onr.news_id FROM organisation_news_read onr WHERE onr.news_id=t.news_id AND onr.user_id=:user_id)'),
        array(
            ':user_id'       => $this->user->user_id,
            ':org_id'        => $this->user->organisation->organisation_id,
            ':site_id'   => $this->user->organisation->site_id,
            ':year_id'   => $this->user->year_id,
            ':form_name'     => $this->user->form_name,
            ':postcode_area' => $this->user->organisation->postcodeArea,
            ':empty'     => ''
        ));
```

Comment: Are you calling this function from `AccountMenu`? Because you're trying to use `$this->user` and like the error says it doesn't have a property with that name.

Comment: Check Relation between `AccountMenu` & `User` Tables. `relations()` function In Model Class.

Comment: Thanks jagsler - I used Yii::app()->controller->user.. and then it worked.. feel free to answer again and i'll accept it as your comment put me in the right direction.